# How to apply jQuery UI button to an html button in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, jquery-ui, button

I have a GridView with a button called btnShowTradeScreenshot. The GridView creates many buttons and I want to apply the jQuery button to it. Here's my relevant GridView code:

```
<asp:GridView 
    ID="grdTrades" 
    runat="server" 
    >            
    <Columns>            
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Screenshot" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <input name="btnShowTradeScreenshot" runat="server" visible='<%# Eval("screenshotId") != DBNull.Value %>' type="button" value='View...' onclick='<%# "ShowImageInNewPage(\"App_Handlers/ImageHandler.ashx?screenshotId=" + Eval("screenshotId") + "\")" %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>            
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I am trying to apply the jQuery using this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () { $("#<%= btnShowTradeScreenshot.ClientID %>").button(); });
</script>
```

Nothing happens and I get the standard button, not the jQuery button. When I look at the page source, I notice that the buttons have mangled names like:

`ctl00$contentMain$grdTrades$ctl05$ctl03`

`ctl00$contentMain$grdTrades$ctl10$ctl03`
etc

Any ideas on how to apply the jQuery to all my buttons?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a class name on the buttons instead of relying on the ClientID; that way you save on JavaScript length and don't need to bind to every specific control.

In JS:

```
// equivalent to $(document).ready(function() {
$(function() {
  $('.customButton').button();
});
```

In ASP.NET:

```
<input type="button" runat="server" class="customButton" .../>
```

Also, if your grid is an AJAX-bound grid, the `<input/>` elements will be recreated and you'll need to rerun the code on the grid to get the styles applied:

```
$('#<%= grdTrades.ClientID %> .customButton').button();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a name selector instead:

```
$('input[name$=btnShowTradeScreenshot]').button();
```

or even better apply a CSS class to your input and then:

```
$('.button').button();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many buttons created and ASP will generate different IDs for them so as to ensure each one has a unique ID. Since $('#...') is aimed at selecting a single uniquely identified element you cannot use it to select multiple buttons.

Try $(':button') to select all button objects. Alternatively you could set each button's class to something like ShowTradeScreenshot and then select them all with $('.ShowTradeScreenshot').